# Is there a filter input to properly embed MP4 to a browser?

Tags: input-formats

I'd like to use input filter emfield to allow users to embed video content (local on server) but can't seem to find the proper syntax for this input filter. Can anyone point me to an online example?

For example, in the main Content Textarea (CKEditor or TinyMCE), my users would like to key in `[[video:/sites/default/files/video/introduction.php]]` and have it rendered in an HTML5 `<video>` and `<source>` tags.

Comment: where do you want to place the video file ? - inside the body field ?

Comment: I'd like for content editors to embed content that lives on the server. These are MP4 video files. Though local, they're small and the site is an Intranet (known bandwidth, known audience).